# Retrieving native ACTIVEX control from custom directory

Tags: c#, .net, mfc, installation, activex

I am very new in C# active X part and its liking with MFC hence this question can be repeated in other forum or question. I tried 3 hours of google but with no result.

there is one third part company providing us a native activeX control and we are using it in our MFC dll application.  ActiveX is successfully launched and working properly when i copied all third part provided activeX dll in "**c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319**" folder and register activeX using "**c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegASM.exe /tlb UseItActiveX.dll**" command.

Now, i want to release my MFC dll into market hence i need to merge third party ACTIVEX dll's into MSI build.

Restriction is, In release environment i have to copy ACTIVEX dlls in "C:\Program Files\UseIt Software\common" folder.

So, how to retrieve local C# ACTIVE_X dll from **C:\Program Files\UseIt Software\common** folder instead of **"c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319"**.

Note: When i copied ACTIVEX dll in **c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319** folder on release environment, all functionality of activeX control working properly.

Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is obsolete.

When it is a COM component, than it gets registered. ANd in the registry data for this COM component the path of the DLL is included.

Typically it doesn't matter were a COM component resides (as long as it has all needed DLLs in Folders that are in the search path).

When the COM component is registered with REGSVR32 or REGASM all required information to execute the control is already placed in the registry and all programs can use it from the folder were it was registered.